# how to code sql select string

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-3.x

I am confusing how can I code in Python.

Following code works from pgsql command line.

```
select * from consultation_tbl where consultation_status in ('S','C','R');
```

But in Python, I have no idea how to code.

```
chat_str = "\'S\',\'C\',\'R\'"
cursor.execute(" \
        SELECT * FROM consultation_tbl
        WHERE consultation_status IN ( %s )", [chat_str])
```

Please give me an advice.

Comment: String substitution could lead to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query with variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217680/sql-query-with-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can use single quotes within double quotes string, This is a valid Python literal string:

```
chat_str = "'S', 'C', 'R'"
```

But I would code like this:

```
# 1) This joins the tokens with ', ' separator. Very useful
chat_str = ', '.join(["'S'", "'C'", "'R'",])

# 2) We use the python3 format() method for strings. 
# The '{}' is replaced. See the official docs
query = "SELECT * FROM consultation_tbl
    WHERE consultation_status IN ({})".format(chat_str)

cursor.execute(query)
```

In both cases, the result string is equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. But I got following error. `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "s" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ation_tbl             WHERE consultation_status IN (S, C, R)` How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems like you have %s in your code and not the {} placeholder

Comment: Thhank you for reply. I use {} in my code. I copy your code and paste it. What is wrong?

Comment: Have you debugged this for checking which is the result string? I need to see what is getting postgresql.

Comment: I may have to use %s if I use postgresql. "{}" doesn't work in my code.

Comment: With %s you can't use fomat(), then I suppose you are using the % string substitution operator, aren't you?

Comment: I tried "{}" first. But it didn't work. Error is `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "s" does not exist LINE 1: ...ation_tbl WHERE consultation_status IN (S, C, R)`. So, I searched to the web and I found information that you have to use %S if you are using postgresql. So, I tried to use %s, but I have no idea how can I code.

Comment: Look at the end. You can read S instead of 'S'. Postgresql thinks you are passing a database field or column, not a character. I think I can mend this in my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156576/discussion-between-madtyn-and-kazzz-studio).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't want to put *data* into the query using hand-rolled sting substitution -- the python sql api lets you pass in a tuple which it will sanitize and put in for you to prevent sql injection. That being said since the list of parms in the IN clause can be dynamic in length you may still need string substitution to create a template query. I've usually seen it look something like this:

```
char_list = ['S', 'C', 'R' ]
qry = "SELECT * FROM consultation_tbl WHERE consultation_status IN ( %s )"
qry %= ",".join("%s" for x in range(len(char_list)))

cursor.execute(qry, chars)
```

Comment: Thank you for an advice. Where chars come from ?