# How do you insert python variables into an sql query?

Tags: python, sql, variables, cs50

I'm working on a cs50 pset7 houses, and I'm writing this sql query:

```sql
 db.execute("ALTER TABLE students ADD firstname varchar(%s);", firstname)
```

but I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 18, in <module>
    db.execute("ALTER TABLE students ADD firstname varchar(%s);"%(firstname))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 21, in decorator
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 385, in execute
    raise e
RuntimeError: near "Adelaide": syntax error
```

What does this mean? And also, what can I use to insert the firstname variable into the query without getting this error message? I think that there must be a different symbol except for `%s`, but when I google it `%s`is the only thing I get. I'm working in CS50 IDE. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query with variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217680/sql-query-with-variables-in-python)

Comment: The query you posted tries to create a varchar field whose size is `Adelaide`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your SQL is wildly off. `ALTER TABLE` is for adding and removing *columns*, changing their types and so on. You apparently want to add a row, and for that you want `INSERT`.

Secondly, and perhaps more important, you should not use Python string formatting to insert values in a query, but whatever mechanism your database interface library provides for this. Typically, your statement would look something like

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO students (firstname) VALUES (%s)", [firstname])
```

though the details depend a bit on the database library (some of them want the placeholder to be `$1`, not `%s`, for example. This should all be in the relevant docs somewhere.

Comment: I do want to add a couloum containing the firstname variable

Comment: @Lostincode the database with users table is supplied in the distro code; you do not want to add the column as stated in this answer, you want to INSERT data into that column. The [cs50 sql library](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/python/#cs50.SQL.execute) uses placeholders, either ? style or named style, not `%s`. [Review the lecture](https://youtu.be/u5pDdEKnbKA?t=4046) from 1:07:00 for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is my example:

```
sql = '''
    select
        company as "name",
        round(sum(loose_paid_sum) / 100.0) * 100 as "sum", 
        sum(loose_paid_count) as "count" 
    from agency_money am WHERE "month" >= ? and "month" <= ? and insurance_company_msp=?
    GROUP by "name"
'''

cursor.execute(sql, (period_start, period_end, insurance_company_msp))
```

so, you must set tuple as second argument of execute!